# AzureAd token refresh CORS error on WebAPI + Angular project

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I'm building an application based on the .Net Core 3.1 + Angular template. The application is using Azure AD to authenticate users.

The backend handle the authentication and force the user to be authenticated.
Here is roughly how it is configured:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  [...]
  services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));

  services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
  {
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
  });
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
[...]
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        await context.ChallengeAsync(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
    else
    {
        await next();
    }
  });
  app.UseSpa();
}
```

This works fine, when landing anywhere on the website, if the user is not authenticated, he is redirected to azure ad for login, redirected back and all the requests to the api is authenticated (using cookies).

The issue is when the token expires. If the user leaves the website opened, the token expires, and then he clicks somewhere, the SPA  triggers a call to the API.
The authentication is not valid anymore so the backend returns a redirect to the azuread login. But it's a XMLHttpRequest, so the call fails with a CORS error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[redacted]/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[redacted]&redirect_uri=[redacted].azurewebsites.net%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=[...]&state=[...]&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0' 
(redirected from 'https://[redacted].azurewebsites.net/api/directories') from origin 'https://[redacted].azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

How can I solve this ? Can I catch the redirect with the angular httpclient to force the client to refresh or something like that ?
Or can I read the azuread cookie to know it is expired before making a call to the API ?
Or maybe there is a way to use the refresh token from the backend ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You should use AzureADBearer authentication for a single page app. The SPA should handle authentication with MSAL.js, not the back-end.

Comment: I used AzureADBearer before, but I wanted to secure the application completely. If the SPA handles the authentication, it needs to be downloaded before being able to redirect the user. If the backend handles it, no request can comes before being authenticated.

Comment: Right, that's true of course. Maybe it would be possible to configure the AJAX requests to not follow redirects and detect the situation somehow?

Comment: As per this thread, it doesn't looks like it is possible to do it this way... https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15165

Comment: Maybe you could catch the CORS error somehow and trigger authentication through a refresh of the page?

Comment: Hello @NicolasC Ae you still looking for help with this question ?

Comment: Well, I found a workaround, I added an angular component to watch if the user is idle, if he is idle for too long, a modal dialog force him to reconnect (reload the app). But it is a workaround, I would prefer a real solution to capture the error and force him to reconnect or challenge the auth...