# asp.net core angular cookie authentication expiry cors error

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an application based on the .Net Core 3.1 + Angular. The application is using OpenID connect to authenticate users.
The backend handle the authentication and force the user to be authenticated. This works fine and all the requests to the api is authenticated (using cookies).

The issue is when the cookie expires. If the user leaves the website opened, the token expires, and then he clicks somewhere, the SPA triggers a call to the API. The authentication is not valid anymore so the backend returns a redirect to the login provider. But it's a XMLHttpRequest, so the call fails with a CORS error."Access to XMLHttpRequest at xyz from origin xyz has been blocked by cors policy".

How can I best solve this?
At the client side, if I catch the error(errorInterceptor) which has Status 0 and so forcefully cause a reload, it again authenticates but this does not seem the best way to do.

```
case 0:
      this.router.navigate(['/Home']).then(() => {
        location.reload(true);
      });
      break;
```

This question is similar to [AzureAd token refresh CORS error on WebAPI + Angular project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63934134/azuread-token-refresh-cors-error-on-webapi-angular-project)

Answer (score 0):

```
 If you are using JWT token then you can install library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-jwt it will help you when token is expired.
```

```
jwtHelper: JwtHelper = new JwtHelper();

useJwtHelper() {
  var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

  console.log(
    this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token),
    this.jwtHelper.getTokenExpirationDate(token),
    this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)
  );
}
```

Or

```
If you are using custom authentication then add one property of expiration date into your token and you can decode that token and handle with that property.
```